# Vue <router-link> not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to set up a Vue app with some simple routing so I can navigate to different pages. I installed Vue-Router through npm and I've tried following a couple tutorials online but, I can't seem to figure out why my  is not clickable or why, when I manually type in the URL, it doesn't change anything. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

main.js:

```html
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import "./vue-api-call/styles.css"
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import About from "./About"
import Home from "./Home";


const routes = [
    {path: '/about', component: About},
    {path: '/home', component: Home}
]

const router = new VueRouter({routes})

createApp(App, router).mount("#app")

export default router
```

App.vue:

```html
<!-- This first part of the file, the template part, is basically like an HTML page. Whatever we put in here will
display when we use 'npm run serve'. -->
<template>
  <!-- The <div> tag is used as a container for HTML elements - which is then styled with CSS or manipulated with
  JavaScript. -->
  <div id="app">
    <!--    <nav>Hello</nav>-->
    <!-- The router-view tag will display info that comes from the router-link tag. More information here:
    https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/#html -->
    <router-view>
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </router-view>
    <Layout>
      <!-- begin form -->
      Add a new video game with the form below:
      <form id="demo">
        <!-- text -->
        <br>
        <p>
          <input type="text" v-model="msg" placeholder="Add Game">
          {{ msg }}
        </p>
        <br>
        <p>
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked">
          {{ checked ? "yes" : "no" }}
        </p>
        <br>
        <!-- select -->
        <p>
          <select v-model="selected">
            <option>one</option>
            <option>two</option>
          </select>
        </p>
        <br>
        <p>
          <button type="submit" v-on:click="createVideoGame()">Submit Form</button>
        </p>
      </form>
      <br>
      <button v-on:click="customer()"> Customer Button</button>
      <br>
      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Customer ID</th>
          <th scope="col">First Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Middle Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Birthday</th>
          <th scope="col">Gender</th>
          <th scope="col">Email</th>
          <th scope="col">Username</th>
          <th scope="col">Is Deleted</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="customer in customerInfo" :key="customer.customerId">
          <td>{{ customer.customerId }}</td>
          <td>{{ customer.cusFirstName }}</td>
          <td>{{ customer.cusLastName }}</td>
          <td>{{ customer.cusMiddleName }}</td>
          <td>{{ customer.dateOfBirth }}</td>
          <td>{{ customer.gender }}</td>
          <td>{{ customer.email }}</td>
          <td>{{ customer.username }}</td>
          <td>{{ customer.isDeleted }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br><br>
      <button v-on:click="videoGame()"> VideoGame Button</button>
      <br>
      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Video Game ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Title</th>
          <th scope="col">Release Year</th>
          <th scope="col">Price</th>
          <th scope="col">Stock</th>
          <th scope="col">Image</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="game in gameInfo" :key="game.videoGameId">
          <td>{{ game.videoGameId }}</td>
          <td>{{ game.videoGameTitle }}</td>
          <td>{{ game.yearReleased }}</td>
          <td>{{ game.price }}</td>
          <td>{{ game.stock }}</td>
          <td>{{ game.videoGameImage }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br><br>
      <button v-on:click="order()"> Order Button</button>
      <br>
      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Order ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Order Date</th>
          <th scope="col">Credit Card Provider</th>
          <th scope="col">Credit Card Number</th>
          <th scope="col">Total</th>
          <th scope="col">Subtotal</th>
          <th scope="col">Discount</th>
          <th scope="col">Customer ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Address ID</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="order in orderInfo" :key="order.orderId">
          <td>{{ order.orderId }}</td>
          <td>{{ order.orderDate }}</td>
          <td>{{ order.creditCardProvider }}</td>
          <td>{{ order.creditCardNumber }}</td>
          <td>{{ order.total }}</td>
          <td>{{ order.subtotal }}</td>
          <td>{{ order.discount }}</td>
          <td>{{ order.customerId }}</td>
          <td>{{ order.addressId }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br><br>
      <button v-on:click="purchase()"> Purchase Button</button>
      <br>
      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Purchase ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Order ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Video Game ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Shipment Date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="[purchase] in [purchaseInfo]" :key="purchase.purchaseId">
          <td>{{ purchase.purchaseId }}</td>
          <td>{{ purchase.orderId }}</td>
          <td>{{ purchase.videoGameId }}</td>
          <td>{{ purchase.shipmentDate }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br><br>
      <button v-on:click="address()"> Address Button</button>
      <br>
      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Address ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Customer ID</th>
          <th scope="col">State ID</th>
          <th scope="col">City</th>
          <th scope="col">Zip</th>
          <th scope="col">Suite Number</th>
          <th scope="col">PO Box</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="address in addressInfo" :key="address.addressId">
          <td>{{ address.addressId }}</td>
          <td>{{ address.customerId }}</td>
          <td>{{ address.stateId }}</td>
          <td>{{ address.city }}</td>
          <td>{{ address.zip }}</td>
          <td>{{ address.suiteNumber }}</td>
          <td>{{ address.poBox }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br><br>
      <button v-on:click="state()"> State Button</button>
      <br>
      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">State ID</th>
          <th scope="col">State</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="state in stateInfo" :key="state.stateId">
          <td>{{ state.stateId }}</td>
          <td>{{ state.state }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br><br>
    </Layout>
  </div>
</template>

<!-- Still not entirely sure what this script part is. Pretty sure it's some functionality stuff added by Vue -->
<script>
import Layout from "./components/Layout.vue"
import axios from "axios"


// import PageHeading from "./components/PageHeading.vue"
// import NavBar from "./components/NavBar.vue"

export default {
  name: 'App', variant: "variant", variantType: "variantType", disableButton: "disableButton",
  username: "", password: "",

  data: () => {
    return {
      // These variables are used above and are what initially is shown above the buttons.
      customerInfo: [],
      gameInfo: [],
      orderInfo: "waiting for order",
      purchaseInfo: "waiting for purchase",
      addressInfo: "waiting for address",
      stateInfo: "waiting for state",
      username: "",
      password: "",
      msg: "",
      checked: true,
      picked: "",
      selected: ""
    }
  },
  components: {
    Layout,
    // NavBar, PageHeading,
  },
  mounted() {
    // this.test()
  },
  methods: {
    // Gets customer info and displays it.
    customer: function () {
      if (this.customerInfo === "waiting for customer") {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost:8000/customers/?format=json')
            .then(response => (this.customerInfo = response.data))
      } else {
        this.customerInfo = "waiting for customer"
      }
    },
    // Gets video game info and displays it.
    videoGame: function () {
      if (this.gameInfo === "waiting for game") {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost:8000/videoGames/?format=json')
            .then(response => (this.gameInfo = response.data))
      } else {
        this.gameInfo = "waiting for game"
      }
    },
    // Gets order info and displays it.
    order: function () {
      if (this.orderInfo === "waiting for order") {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost:8000/orders/?format=json')
            .then(response => (this.orderInfo = response.data))
      } else {
        this.orderInfo = "waiting for order"
      }
    },
    // Gets purchase info and displays it.
    purchase: function () {
      if (this.purchaseInfo === "waiting for purchase") {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost:8000/purchases/?format=json')
            .then(response => (this.purchaseInfo = response.data))
      } else {
        this.purchaseInfo = "waiting for purchase"
      }
    },
    // Gets address info and displays it.
    address: function () {
      if (this.addressInfo === "waiting for address") {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost:8000/addresses/?format=json')
            .then(response => (this.addressInfo = response.data))
      } else {
        this.addressInfo = "waiting for address"
      }
    },
    // Gets state info and displays it.
    state: function () {
      if (this.stateInfo === "waiting for state") {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost:8000/states/?format=json')
            .then(response => (this.stateInfo = response.data))
      } else {
        this.stateInfo = "waiting for state"
      }
    },
    createVideoGame() {
      axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/videoGames/', {
        videoGameId: '111',
        videoGameTitle: 'Test Video Game 1',
        yearReleased: '2021',
        price: '10.00',
        stock: '5',
        videoGameImage: 'testImage'
      })
    },
    // login: function () {
    //   console.log(this.username)
    //   console.log(this.password)
    //   const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs")
    //   bcrypt.compare(this.password, "hash", (err, result) => {
    //     if (err) {
    //       console.error(err)
    //       return
    //     }
    //     console.log(result) // true or false
    //   });
  }
}
// methods: {
//         addUser(){
//            console.log(this.encryptPassword(this.password))
//         },
//         encryptPassword(password)
//           const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
//           return bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
//         },
</script>

<!-- This style tag is for the entire page, I think. If you change something in here, like the background-color, it
will change it on the webpage. It's exactly like the style tag in a CSS/HTML page I'm pretty sure. -->
<!-- if you use the !important; rule, it will override ALL previous styling rules for that specific property on that
element! -->
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #c5fcc5 !important;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid darkgreen;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: please share the package.json file

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to tell Vue to **use** the VueRouter. From the [Official Docs](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript).

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
...
...

const routes = [
    {path: '/about', component: About},
    {path: '/home', component: Home}
];

const router = new VueRouter({routes});

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app'); // <== Here

export default router;
```